# HTML div not setting to 100% in django-template

Tags: html, css, django, django-templates

I am new to HTML. I am developing a web application using Django template,  I am trying to set the height of the div to the maximum of its parent `<body>`. The page is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head><title>Billing Lookup</title>
    <title>Billing Interface</title>
</script>
<style>
    html {
   height: 100%;
}
body {
  min-height: 100%;
}

.main{
    height:100%;
    margin-left:100px;
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-left:80px;
    
}

</style>
    </head>
    <body>
        
       <div id="mm" class="main">
       {% block content %} 
    
         {% endblock %}
        </div>       
    </body>
</html>
```

But when I browse this page in Chrome or Firefox, I see that the **body** and **html** is set to **100%** covering the whole screen, but the div **mm** is not showing 100%. Am I missing something here? Screen shot pasted below.

### Note

If I remove this tag `<!DOCTYPE html>` then I get the height of the div set to 100% which I don't understand. The same happens even in ordinary HTML file without Django env.

### Update

As per the response below, I changed the code to:

```
.main{
        min-height:100%;
        margin-left:100px;
        padding-top:10px;
        padding-left:80px;
        
    }
```

Yet the div height did not change.

I did another modification without success.

```
div{
            min-height:100%;
            margin-left:100px;
            padding-top:10px;
            padding-left:80px;
            
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You must do the same operation like for html and body tags.
I'll also suggest you to separe the css from the html file so you can be smarter in coding
[external css file tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Billing Lookup</title>
<title>Billing Interface</title>
</script>
<style>
html {
height: 100%;
}
body {
min-height: 100%;
}

.main{
height:100%;
margin-left:100px;
padding-top:10px;
padding-left:80px;
}

 div { height: 100%; 
       width: 100%; 
 } 

</style>
</head>
<body>
    
   <div id="mm" class="main">
   {% block content %} 

     {% endblock %}
    </div>       
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Kindly see the updated response above, Thanks

Comment: if you set a margin it will insert your div with a translation of 100px in your case